# Braintree integration with Rails (no switch to production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, braintree

i have an app using braintree payments. I followed the instructions from their site and the sandbox works fine. But in production when i change the api keys with the production keys it still remain the sand box. 
This is the form i use for the payments:

```
<form id="checkout" method="post" action="/checkout">
    <div id="payment-form"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary check_out" value="Pay">
</form>
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.27.0.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                var clientToken = "<%= @token %>";
                braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
                    container: "payment-form"
                });
            </script>
```

and this is the controller code:

```
def checkout
  @order_items = current_order.order_items
  @order = current_order
  @token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
  amount = @order.total
  nonce = params["payment_method_nonce"]

  result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
    amount: amount,
    payment_method_nonce: nonce,
    :options => {
      :submit_for_settlement => true
    }
  )
  if result.success? || result.transaction
    @order.order_status_id = 2
    @order.save
    OrderMailer.order_placed(@order).deliver
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
    session.delete :order_id
    flash[:notice] = 'success'
    redirect_to root_path
  else

  end
end
```

for passing api keys i am using an .env file and the dotenv gem. I deploy this app with Capistrano and i checked the existence of the .env file and if it contains the correct api keys and everything is fine.

Comment: Have you set your Braintree::Configuration.environment to production ?

Comment: Yes of course. Also all keys.

Comment: Thats strange, one thing I would recommend is setting up a Braintree logger. You might be able to get some information from that. 

BraintreeRails::Configuration.logger = Logger.new('log/braintree.log')

Comment: Can you provide me more details or a link for setting up log file? I suppose that this is recommended for local environment.